# Is there a way to have a window contain custom applications in windows?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, windows, winapi

This is kind of outlandish, although not fully, but I was thinking if there is a way to create a window that can contain custom applications(i.e *.exe). For example have a main window and have it contain Application1 in one tab, Application2 in another. Not sure what to tag this exactly, so just throwing some tags that might be of use.

Comment: What is a "custom application"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Any *.exe application

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this. You call the Win32 function `SetParent` to make the application's main window be a child of one of your windows.

However, attempting to do this seldom ends well. Invariably the other application is not expecting you to do this and is not compatible with it. Doing this places severe constrains on the input queues of these processes.

Raymond Chen blogged about this: [Is it legal to call have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx)

> Is it technically legal to have a parent/child or owner/owned relationship between windows from different processes?
>
> Yes, it is technically legal.
>
> It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws.
>
> Creating a cross-thread parent/child or owner/owned window relationship implicitly attaches the input queues of the threads which those windows belong to, and this attachment is transitive: If one of those queues is attached to a third queue, then all three queues are attached to each other. More generally, queues of all windows related by a chain of parent/child or owner/owned or shared-thread relationships are attached to each other.
>
> This gets even more complicated when the parent/child or owner/owned relationship crosses processes, because cross-process coordination is even harder than cross-thread coordination. Sharing variables within a process is much easier than sharing variables across processes. On top of that, some window messages are blocked between processes.
>
> So yes, it is technically legal, but if you create a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned relationship, the consequences can be very difficult to manage. And they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree. (I often see this question in the context of somebody who wants to grab a window belonging to another process and forcibly graft it into their own process. That other process was totally unprepared for its window being manipulated in this way, and things may stop working. Indeed, things will definitely stop working if you change that other window from a top-level window to a child window.)

That you are even allowed to do this is a backward compatibility sop to code written for 16 bit Windows. It really has no place in modern Windows.

Comment: what are you talking about mr...this is not the question...

Comment: If this is not the question then what is your final paragraph talking about?

Comment: it talking about adding .exe file to your winform...like adding windows media player to your winform...(hosting an exe file inside winform)

Comment: Indeed. What did you think I was talking about?

Comment: why did you make it so bulky and complicated?

Comment: Because it is a very complicated subject. In some scenarios you can sort of make it work. But at some point it always breaks down. Also, most of my answer just quotes Raymond. I don't like link only answers.

Comment: right,,,it's kind of ugly...personally i don't recommend that..

Comment: Not so much ugly. More non-functional.

Comment: you have got quite a reputation...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run windows inside of windows using a WinForms MDI host. However, to run a generic .exe file, with no specific standard that you expect it to conform to, would be difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Visual studio

right-click on the toolbox

click "Choose Items..."

wait a stupid amount of time

```
browse to your exe


pick the controls
```

Note that your code will still need to be able to resolve the control at runtime, which means deploying the .NET assembly, or for ActiveX deploying the interop assembly and having the COM dll registered.

To host a separate exe inside a running forms application is not trivial; you would have to spawn the exe (Process.Start) and then use win32 calls to obtain the appropriate window handle, with the intention of re-parenting the window into one of your own. This is a reasonable amount of work, very easy to get wrong, and very brittle (bad thins happen if you bork it). Personally: I simply wouldn't.

Comment: Subclassing is the wrong term. Reparenting is what you mean.